# Remove reminders using NSPredicate iOS

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I am trying to remove reminder using NSPredicates but they are not getting removed.
My code is:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore  predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:[datepicker1 date] ending:[datepicker2 date] calendars:nil]
     [eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders)
     {
         for (EKReminder *reminder  in reminders) {
             [eventStore removeReminder:reminder commit:YES error:nil];
        } }];
```

Comment: What is eventStore? Can you add more code?

Comment: eventStore is an object of EKEventStore

Answer (score 0):

You should also specify the calendars parameters as

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init] ;
NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore  predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:[datepicker1 date] ending:[datepicker2 date] calendars:calendarArray]
     [eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders)
     {
         for (EKReminder *reminder  in reminders) {
             [eventStore removeReminder:reminder commit:YES error:nil];
        } 
}];
```

I hope this should work.

Comment: I tried by using this code but reminders are still there. They are not getting deleted. I am getting one more error when I am trying to delete last reminder from the list i.e. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'